# Yup validation for nested form elements in formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have a nested Formik form which has checkbox in every new set of form fields added. I am trying to add validation in Yup to achieve:

1. Atleast one checkbox to be selected among all the sets.
   [image]
2. Not throw error for other checkboxes if one is selected.
   [image]

Right now, it throws error for other checkboxes if a particular checkbox is selected. Anyone who can guide me on how to prevent this would be really helpful.

Link to the code I have tried so far:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-nested-form-mx15kt

Comment: try using `.test` method of yup. Here is [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hooks-krqg4m?file=/src/Nested.js:601-726) not complete but you can have an idea and it might work. The function in `test` will have access to all yup objects using `from` variable. You can check using `console.log`. You can then loop the `groupedelements` and check if one of the checkbox value is true then `return true` else `return false`. I haven't checked it properly but it might works.

Comment: @Usama, Thank you for the test code. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved using yup `.test`. As I explained in the comment. Also we need to remove `oneOf([true], ...)` as the checkbox can be false now. Here is the working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hooks-krqg4m?file=/src/Nested.js:196-1639)

The Yup schema:

```
const NestedSchema = Yup.object().shape({
dropdown1: Yup.string().required("Select dropdown 1"),
groupedelements1: Yup.array().of(
  Yup.object().shape({
    textinput: Yup.string().required("Enter text"),
    groupedelements2: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        dropdown2: Yup.string().required("Select dropdown 2"),
        checkboxinput: Yup.boolean().test(
          "customValidation",
          "Checkboxes",
          function (val) {
            var { parent, from } = this;
            // console.log(from); //e.g. from[1].value

            console.log(from[1].value.groupedelements2);

            console.log(
              from[1].value.groupedelements2.map(
                (data) => data.checkboxinput
              )
            );

            //Getting checkboxes values from groupedelements2 object
            const checkBoxValues = from[1].value.groupedelements2.map(
              (data) => data.checkboxinput
            );

            var result = false;

            //looping over checkBoxValues array
            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxValues.length; i++) {
              if (checkBoxValues[i]) {
                result = true;
                break; // if one of the checkbox is true then return true and dont validate other checkboxes
              } else {
                result = false;
              }
            }
            console.log(result);
            return result;
          }
        )
      })
    )
  })
)
});
```

Comment: Able to get parent nested elements' values. But however, unable to set / unset error for the remaining checkboxes coz we are able to control only the selected checkbox. Ideally, we should be able to control other checkboxes based on the selected checkbox.